# Using Terminal to copy Aperture files from external hard drive to Mac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, terminal, file-transfer, aperture

I'm a novice Mac user who inherited photo equipment from my photographer Dad. He used Aperture to manage his thousands of photos.

I tried copying a 20 gB file to my computer but it's failed each time. Hard drive = Iomega   Mac user name = Apple. Could someone please write the exact text I'dneed to write in Terminal to copy from Iomega to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `rsync`, which can be easily resumed if interrupted.

```
rsync -azv /Volumes/Iomega ~/Photos/
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried what you suggested but got this error message: rsync -azv /Volumes/Iomega HDD ~/Photos/
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Volumes/Iomega" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Users/appe/HDD" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]

Comment: The name of the aperture file I'm trying to copy from Iomega to Apple is "Aperture Library Alaska20g" I'd appreciate your using this info to again type the text I should enter. Many thanks.